# IndexError: index 149 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 149

Tags: python, arrays, arraylist, sift

I have searched about the following error but could not find the correct solution. The error occurred in the below code.

```
inputs=numpy.zeros((features,128),'f')
offset = 0
for index in range(len(seqTags)):
    d=rawInputs[index]
    w,h=d.shape
    for i in range(90):
            inputs[offset,:]=d[i,:]
            offset+=1

//The varriable i runs 90 times correctly when index= 0.
//When index =1 and i=59 it stuck with this error.
// The seqTags= number of files
```

ERROR:

```
inputs[offset,:]=d[i,:]

IndexError: index 149 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 149
```

Any help would be highly appreciated !

Comment: I found this link useful to understand the cause of this error, https://andreask.cs.illinois.edu/cs357-f14/public/demos/00-intro/python-demo/2-numpy/02-indexing.html still struggling :)

Answer (score 1):

Computers count from `0`, so a list or array `d` with size 149 has the members `d[0]..d[148]`.

Index `149` tries to look at the non-existent `150`th member of the array, resulting in the error you saw.

Comment: but the len(d) == 90 and this code runs fine when index is 0. it means it executes all values of i (i.e., 90), the problem occured when i=59 and index =1